# IOS speed index for list view

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, listview, uicollectionview

I want to test the speed my app loads a list view and compare to the apps competitors. (like a speed index test)

Is there any existing service I can do this on?

Is there any functionality on xcode to test this?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually I would use [Instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/)

Comment: antonio081014 how do use instruments for this?

Comment: As you probably have read the link I attached, you could use Time Profiler to analyze your performance.